# Attach more than one IAM inline policy from cloudformation to the same role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am checking to see if we could attach more than one IAM policy with cloud formation.
I am already attaching an Managed Policy and i am able to attach and inline policy but wanted to check if i could attach more than one inline policy.

I would want to attach to the same role

1) Managed Policy
2) Inline Policy - 1
3) Inline Policy - 2

Thanks
Nataraj

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is completely possible. The relevant fields will be `ManagedPolicyArns` and `Policies`.

```
Resources: 
  RootRole: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:policy/myname/ManagedPolicy'
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: "Inline Policy 1"
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "*"
                Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: "Inline Policy 2"
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "*"
                Resource: "*"
```

For more details/callouts check out the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html

Comment: Cheruvian Thank you very much for your help.